# NIOS II operating system support

Tags: operating-system, fpga, rtos, nios

I am trying to understand operating system support for the nios II soft processor.

Altera and the web provide some answers to this, but searching forums is where most information is kept.

Trying to gauge the amount of effort it would take to get some kind of RTOS with Ethernet support on the nios ii.

What OS options are there and is there a large porting effort?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RTOS [ucos ii from Micrium](https://www.micrium.com/) with Altera DE2. You can just create a project with support for the RTOS.